# Return Yes or No instead of True or False in Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is regarding Powershell Script.

I want to show the output to Yes or No instead of True or False in whole script wherever it return True or False. (without using if and else).

For Example, if user's password is expired, it should show 'Yes' instead of 'True' and vice-versa.

I'm writing a code(GUI form) in which there are many outputs (in Boolean True and False).

To make it user friendly, I want to return Yes or No instead of True or False wherever there is Boolean output.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is nonsensical, people understand the difference between true and false.

Comment: I don't think everyone does. When someone ask me if user's account is active, I say yes or no, not True or False.

Comment: There's a difference between understanding the meaning of a word and actively using it in a conversation. What is your opposition to using if else?

Answer (score 4):

If you generally want to map the Boolean output of a script/cmdlet/function to `'Yes'` or `'No'`, you can use something like the following:

```
('No', 'Yes')[(...)] # map output of ... to 'Yes', if $True, to 'No' otherwise
```

E.g.:

```
PS> ('No', 'Yes')[((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq 'Monday')]
Yes # on 2018-05-28
```

This takes advantage of the fact that indexing (`[ ]`) forces its argument to an *integer* (`[int]`), and a *Boolean* (`[bool]`) is forced to an integer by mapping `$False` to `0` and `$True` to `1`.

Note that if the command (`(...)`) returns something that cannot be coerced to an integer, `$null` is returned as the overall result (try `(1, 2)['not-a-number']`, for instance).

To force *any* output, irrespective of its type, to a Boolean and therefore to either index `0` or `1` (which in the case at hand maps to `'No'` or `'Yes'`), cast to `[bool]`:

```
('No', 'Yes')[[bool] (...)]
```

That will map `$False`, `0`, or *empty* output (empty string, `$null`, empty collections, ...) to `'No'`, and everything else (including `$True`) to `'Yes'`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50575918/712649), you can construct a filter that replaces boolean values in the pipeline with the string "Yes" or "No":

```
filter BoolToYesNo {
  if($_ -is [bool]){
    $_ = @('No','Yes')[$_]
  }
  return $_
}
```

Then stick it at the end of your pipeline:

```
PS C:\> .\myscript.ps1
True
False
Something else completely
True

PS C:\> .\myscript.ps1 |BoolToYesNo
Yes
No
Something else completely
Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing any code you have tried / or are working with. 
So, please post what you have so we have a point of reference.

Also, what's your opposition to using if/Then and outputting Yes/No, if it gets you what you want to display?

If you are using cmdlets, which only output Boolean true / false, you have to deal with that, either use If/Then or a case/select or try/catch statement.

You could also, just use a -replace option for those true/false items depending on what you are doing / using.

Yet, again, without you showing anything, it's all guessing at this time.